# Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, variables, var

I'm struggling to get the result of one variable change another unrelated variable.

I have a script that is generating a random number between 0 and 19, which attaches itself to the global variable "index". I'd like to have another script that can read the result of the "index" variable and assign the appropriate text response from a different array, and post that text into a new variable (lets call it "response"). These two variables need to match up as well, the text ("response") following the associated number ("index").  e.g if the var index=0 then the var response= "good", when var index=1 then var response="bad" so on an so forth for all 20 possible outcomes put each array.

It seems pretty simple, but has eluded me accept for very complex and inefficient (i.e incompatible) means.

Thank you so much in advance, there's some very talented peeps out there!

Thanks for your prompt responses!

Here's some of the code.

```
    var answers= new Array(20);
    for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)
        answers[i] = new Image();
        answers[0].src = 'images/answer1.jpg';
        //so on an so forth from 0 - 19
    var index;  

    function askQuestion(){
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (answers.length));}
```

So I've got the var index returning values which trigger the associated image, but then want to use the result of the index var to output an associated text too (using the another var). I can't believe I'm stumped on such a simple thing! I think I'm over complicating it with multiple variables or doubling the code again. Perhaps I'm just stuffing up the syntax. Damn, my javascript coding aint the greatest. Shouldn't of dropped out of maths all those years ago! Any ideas?

Comment: can you post some of your code, it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need this?

```
var response = yourDifferentArray[window.index];
```

The syntax `window[varName]` allows you to retrieve the value of a global variable from anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but can't seem to get it to work. Maybe my syntax is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you could try to make the `index` variable global with `function askQuestion(){ window.index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (answers.length));}`.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Got it working! I knew it was simple, but was trying to be too tricky!

Comment: Thank you for being so grateful, that's really nice, not everybody is... Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

So it was really simple. My problem was being too tricky (and a syntax error) by trying to use multiple scripts which weren't communicating. Here's the result.

```
var answers= new Array(20);
for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)
    answers[i] = new Image();
    answers[0].src = 'images/answer1.jpg';
    //so on an so forth from 0 - 19
var index;    
var remarks = ["remark0","remark1"] //..so on 0-19
var response;

function askQuestion(){
    window.index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (answers.length));}
    response = remarks[window.index];
```

Thank you so much for the help! GOLD STAR!!